# Getting undefined when accessing a property from `me` in javascript even though it exists

Tags: javascript, function, shopware

Can anyone explain when I do a `console.log(me)` in a prototype function to extend I get the `article` property as you can see [here](http://prntscr.com/kgm1su) but when I do a `console.log(me.article)` I get `undefined` [see here](http://prntscr.com/kgm33a)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT:**

```
var _createLeftElements = Shopware.apps.Article.view.detail.Base.prototype.createLeftElements;

Shopware.apps.Article.view.detail.Base.prototype.createLeftElements = function() {

    var me =this, articleId = null, additionalText = null;

    console.log(me);
    console.log(me.article)

    .
    .  // some code here
    .

    return [
        me.supplierCombo,
        me.nameField,
        me.mainDetailAdditionalText,
        me.numberField,
        {
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            name: 'active',
            fieldLabel: me.snippets.active,
            inputValue: true,
            uncheckedValue:false
        },
        {
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            name: 'isConfigurator',
            fieldLabel: me.snippets.configurator.fieldLabel,
            inputValue: true,
            uncheckedValue:false
        }
    ];
};
```

**EDIT#2**

Have put this code block inside a function and am calling that at the end of the file. Not sure if this detail mattered but just wanted to be thorough. Thanks

Comment: You're gonna have to provide us with some code.

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: ok have updated the question. please kindly have a look

Comment: am still stuck on this if anyone can provide any help. thanks